# Split array in ko template

Tags: magento2, template, array

I have a array with following structure in ko template

```
 styleBasedProductsDetails = {{
                "image_url": "media/images/home-page/1.jpg",
                "link_url": "push-up-bra-online/"
            },
            {
                "image_url": "media/images/home-page/5.jpg",
                "link_url": "push-up-bra-online/"
            },
            {
                "image_url": "media/images/home-page/2.jpg",
                "link_url": "bra-online/underwired-bra/"
            }}
```

How to split each element in this array like... styleBasedProductsDetails[0]['link_url'] without using foreach

Answer (score 0):

That isn't an array, it's an object containing objects. An array would look like so (notice the `[` and `]`):

```
    styleBasedProductsDetails = [
        {
            "image_url": "media/images/home-page/1.jpg",
            "link_url": "push-up-bra-online/"
        },
        {
            "image_url": "media/images/home-page/5.jpg",
            "link_url": "push-up-bra-online/"
        },
        {
            "image_url": "media/images/home-page/2.jpg",
            "link_url": "bra-online/underwired-bra/"
        }
    ]
```

---

To loop through it in the template use the [foreach binding](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html):

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: product">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: link_url"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: image_url"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

That will output the links to text but you get the idea.

---

To loop through it in Javascript you don't need Knockout, use [foreach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```
this.styleBasedProductsDetails.forEach(function(product) {
  console.log(product.link_url);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> styleBasedProductsDetails()[0]['image_url']